# How to fire bullets in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a platform 2D game. So far made like 2 levels and I'm currently working on a boss level. I used a free model blue Sci-Fi type of gun, and I don't know how to make it fire bullets. The gun is attached to the player,its always pointing in the direction of the mouse,and once the raycast detects its colliding with the boss layer,it draws a red line (on top of the already drawn blue line). I hope i explained it so you can understand what i mean. Here's the code.

```cs
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float fireRate = 0;
    public float Damage = 5;
    public LayerMask whatToHit;

    private float timeToFire = 0;
    Transform firePoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        firePoint = transform.FindChild("FirePoint");
        if(firePoint == null){
            Debug.LogError("No FirePoint. What?");
        }
    }

    public float offset;

    void Update()
    {
        Shoot();
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

        if(fireRate == 0) {
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                Shoot();
            }
        }

        else {
            if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Time.time > timeToFire) {
                timeToFire = Time.time + 1/fireRate;
                Shoot();
            }
        }

    }
    void Shoot() {
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
        Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (firePointPosition, mousePosition-firePointPosition, 100, whatToHit);
        Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, (mousePosition-firePointPosition)*100, Color.blue);
        if(hit.collider != null){
            Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to fire bullets instead of raycasting, you have to add a bullet class

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Something like https://forum.unity.com/threads/firing-a-bullet-from-a-gun.701327/ or https://answers.unity.com/questions/1105218/how-to-make-an-object-shoot-a-projectile.html or https://answers.unity.com/questions/1658741/how-to-fire-projectile-in-direction-character-is-f.html

Comment: Alright,thanks ill try everything i can cause im thinking of making this game my first play store publish.

Answer (score 4):

Just [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) a prefab. Then destroy it after a bit of delay, or after it has traveled a set distance.
You can create a prefab by making an object (for example a cube) in the scene, adding scripts to it and drag it into the project window (where your files are), then drag the prefab from there into the slot on your script

```
// add this variable to your Script, this is where you drag your prefab in the inspector
public GameObject bulletPrefab;

// Put this in your shoot function
Instantiate(bulletPrefab, GUNTRANSFORM, GUNTRANSFORM.rotation, transform);
```

On the Prefab you place a MonoBehaviour like this:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 20;

    void Update() 
    {
        transform.Translate((transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

References: [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), [Transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html), [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpxim8YbsMk)

Comment: So like for example:
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown) {
(Your script)
}
and it should work?

Comment: I Just edited the answer, since it didnt explain it that much, sorry

Comment: Alright,thank you,but what does GUNTRANSFORM and GUNTRANSFORM.rotation mean?

Comment: This would be the transform of your gun, or the point from which the bullet will move

Comment: So like the empty gameobject on the tip of my gun?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Alright thank you for this answer,ill try the code right now,ill update you once im done.

Comment: Sure, if you have any problems, just post a comment

Comment: When i type public GameObject bulletPrefab;  it should like add a little section in the gun inspector and i should drag the prefab into it? If yes,then it didn't work somehow

Comment: Did you add the bullet script to the bullet prefab?

Comment: Yeah and when i go into the gun's inspector and scroll down to the script,there is no little section where you drag and drop the prefab in.

Comment: Where did you put the bulletprefab variable?

Comment: First i created the variable before void Start() and void Update() and then i used it later in the shoot function. If you dont understand what im telling you (sorry if you dont im new to unity),add me on discord. itzjustaki#1894